# Como copiar vários arquivos excel em um banco de dados access 2010 usando vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access, office-2013

sou novo em programação VBA. Preciso de um código vba em excel que copie vários arquivos do excel para uma tabela do access.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum. Por favor, faça o [tour]. E edite a sua pergunta para torná-la mais específica (por exemplo: qual exatamente é a sua dificuldade na implementação de tal código?).

Answer (score 1):

Essa **talvez** seja uma solução possivel, usando ACE.OLEDB:

```
Sub Test()
    accessFilePath = "C:\someDB.accdb"
    Call ExecuteSQLCmd("INSERT INTO `" & accessFilePath & "`.`Table` (col1,col2,col3) SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM [Sheet1$]", accessFilePath)
 End Sub

Sub ExecuteSQLCmd(cmd As String, accessFilePath as String )

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sql As String

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFilePath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

    If Not (cnn Is Nothing) Then
        'Execute Sql
        cnn.Execute (cmd)
        'Close
        cnn.Close
    End If
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```